# Robot Framework test case naming convention and running with bat-file

Tags: batch-file, robotframework

I have a question about Robot Framework test case naming conventions and running a test case with .bat-file on Windows-10 laptop. 
During my limited experience of working with Robot Framework I have been mostly using RIDE-editor and there has not been many problems when running with that.

When looking at test case naming conventions in a link below a good way seems to be to put
space between words. Very simple example being `Open Browser` so there is a space between those 
two words belonging to a test case name. Longer example would be `Empty Username And Password`                                                                  I personally like that kind of style with spaces.

https://github.com/robotframework/HowToWriteGoodTestCases/blob/master/HowToWriteGoodTestCases.rst#test-case-names

However I noticed that if I try to run from .bat-file like this.

robot -t testcasename testsuitename.robot

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\developer\Robot
robot -t Open Browser Demosuite.robot
```

Then command prompt just blinks shortly before disappearing and running test case like that does not work. When running with RIDE-editor there is no problem with running.

But if I rename test case like this.

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\developer\Robot
robot -t Open_Browser Demosuite.robot
```

That works. So is this expected behaviour that it should not work with spaces when running from .bat?

Robot Framework-code:

```
Resource          Resources/CommonResources.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Open Browser
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com    Firefox
```

Comment: Yes, either that, change the whitespace to underscore yourself, or - surround the argument in double quotes (that's the normal way of passing such values in Windows). E.g. `robot -t "Open Browser" Demosuite.robot`

Comment: `cmd` sees each whitespace as a separator of commands and parameters. robot does the same, it is expecting a single parameter after the `-t` switch. to make it a single parameter we use double quotes so the internal space is ignored and seen as part of the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to how windows and other operating systems handle arguments on the command line. Windows knows nothing about robot and doesn't know anything about the `-t` argument or what it expects. When it sees `robot -t Open Browser Demosuite.robot` it sees the following:

```
* command name: robot
* argument 1: -t
* argument 2: Open
* argument 3: Browser
* argument 4: Demosuite.robot
```

Notice that "Open" and "Browser" are treated as two separate arguments.

Passing arguments with spaces, whether with robot or any other command line tool, requires that you use quotes. In your case you could do `robot -t "Open Browser" Demosuite.robot`, or as you observed you can use an underscore in place of the space which robot (and likely *only* robot) will convert to spaces for you.